# Don't understand recursive backtracking

Tags: java

I understand that this is a "vague" question, but I completed a data structures class at my college and still do not understand how recursive backtracking works. I don't understand the "magic" of recursion and struggle to write recursive backtracking algorithms. Like say I give an example here that is a a template for recursive backtracking:

```
void findSolutions(n, other params) {
    if (found a solution) {
       solutionsFound++;
       displaySolution();
    if (solutionsFound >= solutionTarget) {
       System.exit(0);
       return;
      }
   }
    for (val = first to last) {
       if (isValid(val, n)) {
           applyValue(val, n);
           findSolutions(n + 1, other params);
           removeValue(val, n);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand how this actually works. And I'm kind of tired of having someone tell me that I just have to believe it does. I'd really like an in depth explanation of how recursion actually works and how to write it. 
I believe that recursion is an important concept to understand for technical interviews and such and I really want to be able to write code when I need to solve problems like these. Any tips would be greatly appreciated for explaining this as well as good resources to look at and study as well.

Comment: I would suggest reading this article http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/recursion/explanation-of-recursion/ It will help you understand it better.

Comment: If you really do not understand recursion, this question is too broad. If it's just backtracking that you do not understand: It's just a depth first search for solutions... Every method call stands for one step in assembling a complete solution. BTW: `System.exit(0);
       return;` is a nice joke

Answer (score 1):

**Simple examples of recursion.**

Let's say you want a method `sum(n)` that sums the numbers from `0` to `n`.

Using a simple `for` loop, that easy enough to understand:

```java
private static int sum(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        sum += i;
    return sum;
}
```

```java
System.out.println(sum(5)); // prints: 15
```

---

Now, if you were to do this using recursion, there would be two ways.

One way would be to add a second parameter with the sum calculated so far, initially set to `0`, and then make a recursive call like this:

```java
private static int sum(int n, int sum) {
    if (n == 0)
        return sum;
    return sum(n - 1, sum + n);
}
```

```java
System.out.println(sum(5, 0)); // prints: 15
```

This is known as tail-recursion, because the recursive call is the *very last* thing done in the method. It is a common pattern in [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming).

---

The other way is using recursive backtracking, and is what you asked about.

Here you make a recursive call to calculate `sum(n-1)`, until you get to `sum(0)`, which of course is `0`. You then add `n` to that sum and return it.

```java
private static int sum(int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    return sum(n - 1) + n;
}
```

```java
System.out.println(sum(5)); // prints: 15
```

This is using backtracking, because it make the recursive call *first*, to calculate the "lower" value, then add to that value on the return from the lower call, i.e. when backtracking.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion usually becomes clear when you visualize the easy examples at first, (factorial, fibonacci, etc...)

when you trace the Function call stack and see what is happening, you start to understand what is happening, however you shouldn't have to trace the function calls everytime you design a recursive algoeithm.

After the first few examples you understand that recursion can solve problems with "Lazy Coding", as my professor likes to call it.

Take for example searching for an element in an array recursively,
you will take the array A, the int target and an int index.

When writing recursively, your first question should be: When do i stop?
in the above example, you either find the element (A[index]==target),
or you have searched the whole array and have nothing to search anymore (index >= A.size()).

so now we know how to stop, but where is the "Lazy coding" part, well recursion is basically like: i am too lazy to look through this whole array, i will search only one element at the index i am at, if i find it, great!
If not, let someone else search the array.

```
int LinearSearch(int[] A, int target, int index){

   if(index >= A.length()) return -1; // searched the whole array

   if(A[index] == target) return index; //found the element

   return LinearSearch(A,target,index+1); //search the next index   
  }
```

The point from this example is, people tell you to "believe the recursion works" because after seeing enough examples, you dont have to look too deep into what the recursion is doing, you are thinking out loud (like the search example above) what the starightforward no brainer idea is, and you're implementing it.

The same principle is done in recursive backtracking:

you have no "smart" algorithm to solve a given problem, so you bruteforce your way, a type of "shuffle and check" where you are trying all possible combinations and checking whether your current shuffle is a solution.

A great problem to start backtracking with is the N-Queens problem, as it's pseudocode is literally lazy coding

```
Boolean 8Queens(int[] board, int row){

    if (row = = 8) return true;

   for (int col = 0; col < 8 ; col++)
   {

        if (isSafe(board,row,col)){
            board[row] = col;     //Place Queen
    
        if (8Queens(board, row+1)) 
            return true;    
   }    
}

  return false;
    }
```

The recursion tree, or more specifically the search tree looks like this:

[Search Tree for the 4-Queens problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57I73.png)

We are simply going row by row, and checking whether it is safe to place a queen in this (row, col) and continue doing so until we have either placed all queens or tried all possible configurations and could find a solution.

The Bottom line is: solve enough basic recursion problems to practice your
"Lazy Coding skills", and as you progress you will notice is becoming much easier to understand what is happening under the hood.
Recursive backtracking is simply, Think of the easiest no brainer solution, and write it.

Hope this answers your question.